# Storm off vs storm out

Tags: phrasal-verbs, particles

Is there any difference between these two? Can I say:

> *He had a row and stormed **off/out**?*

Comment: Stormed off out be more of a general term while stormed out is more specifically leaving a room

Comment: Both are acceptable, with the 'out' variant being more popular: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stormed+out%2Cstormed+off&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstormed%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstormed%20off%3B%2Cc0

Comment: This has nothing to do with "stormed", it's about the two prepositions. They mean different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sound correct to me. The only caveat I have is that I think "stormed out" only really applies if there's a room to storm out of. If someone was leaving an open field in a huff, I'd say "stormed off" instead.

Comment: *A room out of which to storm*, shurely

Comment: *surely*, surely